# Show all opened windows form different desktop to taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, virtual-desktop

Can I show all opened windows form different desktop to taskbar?
It only shows opened windows on the current desktop, I hope it can show me all and if I click the application it will lead me to the desktop which it was opened on.

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of multiple desktops?

Comment: But sometimes I want this function like OSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found the setting that I need.
System -> MultiTasking -> virtual desktop -> show windows they are open -> all desktops